# Differential equations, solving for a chemical rate of change.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, chemistry

> Two chemicals $\mathrm{A}$ and $\mathrm{B}$ are put together in a solution where they react to form a compound $\mathrm{X}$. The rate of increase of the mass, $x\,\rm kg$, of $\mathrm{X}$ is proportional to the product of the masses of unreacted $\mathrm{A}$ and $\mathrm{B}$ present at time, $t\,\rm min$. It takes $1\,\rm kg$ of $\mathrm{A}$ and $3\,\rm kg$ of $\mathrm{B}$ to form $4\,\rm kg$ of $\mathrm{X}$. Initially, $2\,\rm kg$ of $\mathrm{A}$ and $3\,\rm kg$ of $\mathrm{B}$ are put together in solution, and $1\,\rm kg$ of $\mathrm{X}$ forms in one minute.

What I deciphered from this is only:

1. $A + B = Xt$, only true for $t = 1$ (doesn't help at all).
2. $dx/dt = 1$, when $t = 1$.

How can I set up a differential equation expressing $dx/dt$ as a function of $x$?

Comment: The rate is proportional to the *product* of the masses of unreacted A,B. So if $a$ is the amount of $A$ and $b$ is the amount of $b$ then $dx/dt=kab$ for some number $k$ that you haven't been told. Additionally, the stoichiometry tells you that $da/dt=(-1/4)dx/dt$ (each bit of X you gain loses you a quarter of that much A) and $db/dt=(-3/4)dx/dt$ (each bit of X you gain loses you a quarter of that much B). So you have a system of three nonlinear ODEs. Can you solve it?

Comment: @Ian Yes I managed, thanks for the input

Comment: Minor error in my previous comment, it should say "every 4 bits of X you gain loses you 3 bits of B".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$dA/dt= (-1/4)(dx/dt)$
$dB/dt=(-3/4)(dx/dt)$
This gives us with $A=2-(1/4)x$ and $B=3-(3/4)x$
We can interpret that $dx/dt =kab$, for some number $k$.
Now we sub in the values of A and B into the equation dx/dt.
This leaves us with $dx/dt= [3k(8 − x)(4 − x)]/16$

Comment: Other than the lack of LaTeX formatting and a possible algebra error towards the end (I'm not sure $k(2-x/4)(3-3x/4)$ simplifies like that) I don't see why this got downvoted.